# Xerox Workcentre 3025 scanner is not working (Ubuntu 17.04)

Tags: drivers, printing, scanner, xerox

Unfortunately I have a Xerox Workcentre 3025_NI multifunction printer and after installing the official driver on my Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 the scanner does not work, only the printer. Under 16.04 the printer and the scanner also work. I don't understand why.

[Official driver here.](http://www.support.xerox.com/support/workcentre-3025/downloads/huhu.html?operatingSystem=linux&fileLanguage=en_GB)

Comment: so you downloaded Xerox_WorkCentre_3025_Linux-Driver.tar.gz and its install script covers both scanner and printer? `cd Downloads` and `tar -xzvf Xerox_WorkCentre_3025_Linux-Driver.tar.gz` and `cd uld` and `./install.sh` would be the needed lines

Comment: Yes, "install.sh" script install both scanner and printer.  ![Screenshot](http://imgur.com/IAv2hp7)

Comment: I see in the file xerox_mfp.conf that lives inside /etc/sane.d ...... that there are entries for some of the Xerox WorkCentre devices; but not for the 3025 that you have; could you tell us what `lsusb` gives please for your Xerox; when it is plugged in and turned on; I am wondering whether adding an entry for it might help;

Comment: ![Here is the screenshot of the command](http://imgur.com/33Wysvh)

Comment: [Command output here:](http://text-share.com/view/b5ef36e9)

Comment: so you if install the text editor that is called gedit with the command `sudo apt install gedit` and then open the file xerox_mfp.conf with the command `gksudo gedit /etc/sane.d/xerox_mfp.conf` and scroll to the bottom of the file and edit one of the WorkCentre entries; so it now says `#Xerox WorkCentre 3025` on the top line and `usb 0x0924 0x42da` on the line below; SAVE: CLOSE; reboot; I wonder if that helps at all

Comment: Now I have a little success: the system detects the scanner, but after starting the scanning process, the Xerox Workcenter restart yourself. ![Here is the screenshot:](https://imgur.com/a/NJkkK) I tried the gscan2pdf and Gimp but these programs do the same things: start to scanning and then the Xerox shut down and restart.

Comment: if you add your scanner to the libsane.rules file with `gksudo gedit /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane.rules` and scroll down as you did before to one of the WorkCentre entries and add `ATTRS{idVendor}=="0924", ATTRS{idProduct}=="42da",`in the right place .. any joy after a reboot?

Comment: So, at first, thanks for your help, you are very patient. I can report a new succeeding: [I can scan without any issue](http://imgur.com/pPfab1a), so I can use the scanner now. Thanks!

Comment: pleased to hear it works; we learn too from your successes

Answer (score 8):

I found an answer [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/+bug/1728012).

I run the following two commands:

a) `sudo ln -sfr /usr/lib/sane/* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane`

b) `sudo adduser $USER lp`

Then, I updated the file `/etc/sane.d/xerox_mfp.conf` using `sudo vi /etc/sane.d/xerox_mfp.conf` by adding the follwong two lines:

```
#Xerox WorkCentre 3025
usb 0x0924 0x42da
```

I saved and closed the file. And finally, reboot.

It worked fine.

Comment: This was for ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: This worked for me but i did not ran sudo adduser $USER lp . My problem : https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/install-driver-for-xerox-3025-scanner-not-working/18683/5

Comment: Does this method work for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Comment: to Arn yes. I upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04 and still working !

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 22.04 lts !

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about 17.04. But in 16.04 Xerox driver does not work. Since it is rebranded Samsung M2070, you can use samsung driver (V1.00.37_00.99) http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/wireless-mono-multifunction-printer-xpress-m2070

Printing works out of the box. Scanner discovery over network does not work. But workarround like `simple-scan "smfp:net;PRINTER_IP_ADDRESS"` does the trick.

EDIT:
And just got scanner autodiscovery working by allowing port 22161 in firewall
`sudo ufw allow from 10.0.0.0/24 to port 22161`
Of course replace 10.0.0.0/24 by your network range.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to install Samsung drivers from the following page as they are deb packaged and automatically adds your device with udev: [The Samsung Unified Linux Driver Repository](https://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/)

Answer (score 0):

This might be a solution for you: https://www.hamrick.com/vuescan/xerox_workcentre_3025.html#technical-information
They seem to be a boutique software company offering scanner solutions for Linux, MacOS, and Windows. I had a similar problem looking for a Linux solution for my Xerox Documate 510. I have not tried it yet but it appears to be the best alternative.

Answer (score 0):

The solution given on the [Xerox Forum](https://forum.support.xerox.com/t5/Copying-Faxing-Scanning/Xerox-Workcentre-3225-scanner-xerox-driver-don-t-work-on-18-04/m-p/238335#M11687) worked for me for WorkCentre 3225 on 20.04. Try it. It may work for you too.