# Xerox Workcentre 3025 scanner is not working (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: drivers, 18.04, printing, scanner, xerox

I read this  [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927265/xerox-workcentre-3025-scanner-is-not-working-ubuntu-17-04). 
Also I have Xerox Workcentre 3025 multifunction printer and Ubuntu 18.04.

I do the same steps  to install this device. 
Printer works well, but scanner not.

When device is in standby I run `gscan2pdf` and device wakes up.
But if i try to scan, nothing happened and this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kwmhy.jpg .

```
$ lsusb 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0924:42da Xerox
```

The contents of `xerox_mfp.conf` is

```
#Xerox WorkCentre 3025
usb 0x0924 0x42da
```

The file `/lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane.rules` does not exists, but `/lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane1.rules` exists.

I added

```
# Xerox WorkCentre 3025
ATTRS{idVendor}=="0924", ATTRS{idProduct}=="42da"
```

lines also.

What is wrong?

Comment: I have the same problem. The scanner worked fine in 14.04. More details here: https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/install-driver-for-xerox-3025-scanner-not-working/18683/5

Comment: I found the solution. I posted the link as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you edit the file xerox_mfp.conf that sits inside /etc/sane.d with the command

```
gedit admin:///etc.sane.d/xerox_mfp.conf
```

with

```
#Xerox WorkCentre 3025
usb 0x0924 0x42da
```

I wonder if that would help; do a reboot after you edit the file;

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work.

Comment: @pdc your solution lacks

    'sudo ln -sfr /usr/lib/sane/* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane'

Answer (score 0):

The solution is here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1062147/484859

I did not ran:

```
sudo adduser $USER lp
```

Comment: This unfortunately didn't work for me.

Comment: I recently used it in ubuntu 20.04 but after installing the print and scanner by running install.sh from the driver archive from xerox.

Comment: I did that too, on Ubuntu 18.04. It didn't work. (Printer works; device wakes up with `scanimage -L`, but ultimately isn't recognized.)

Comment: Maybe you need to run the user command also. I used pluma insfead of vi to edit and save that file.