# What can I do to make Ubuntu to detect my scanner?

Tags: 20.04, scanner, xerox

I have a Xerox 3025 Scanner connected via Wi-Fi on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Firstly I tried to use unified driver configurator but this doesn't work also I tried to install drivers manually. Secondly I started to use third party apps like `xsane` and `skanlink` but surprisingly this also doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: I believe this is answered here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/927265/xerox-workcentre-3025-scanner-is-not-working-ubuntu-17-04

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xerox Workcentre 3025 scanner is not working (Ubuntu 17.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927265/xerox-workcentre-3025-scanner-is-not-working-ubuntu-17-04)

Comment: unfortunately no

Comment: Just after plugging the scanner in, try to run `dmesg` (or look into /var/log/dmesg), the last lines should show if anything has been identified. Eventually run `dmesg`before plugging the scanner in too, so you know which lines has been added.